# Inserting an array to mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to insert a form data into mysql database using php and jquery ajax But i can't find a way to use that array and use in sql query

> **HOW CAN I INSERT THIS OUTPUT INTO MYSQL QUERY**

**This is my ajax code**

```
var i = JSON.stringify(e.serializeObject(), null, 2);

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: "form="+ i, 
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
            console.log(html);

            }
            });
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['form'];
print_r($data);
```

**Output**

```
{
  "user_edit_uname_control": "demo",
  "user_edit_position_control": "Web Developer",
  "user_edit_address_control": "123 xxx xxx",
  "user_edit_city_control": "city",
  "user_edit_phone": "00042542424",
  "user_edit_dob_control": "00.00.000",
  "val_radio_gender": "m",
  "user_edit_personal_info_control": "s ssfsf s   s sf sf",
  "user_g_cu": "",
  "user_g_per": "",
  "user_g_yer": "",
  "user_g_degre": "",
  "Schol_twele_per": "",
  "Schol_twele_yer": "",
  "Schol_twele_board": "",
  "Schol_ten_per": "",
  "Schol_ten_yer": "",
  "Schol_ten_board": "",
  "checkbox_public_view": "on"
}
```

Comment: see [json_decode](http://docs.php.net/json_decode) and [Prepared statements and stored procedures](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: `"student_name": "Robert' ; DROP TABLE students; -- "`

Answer (score -1):

if you want to store the array in one cell in the database you can use `serialize()` to convert the array to a string and store it in DB

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php